# conversion of date format angular and typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime

How can I convert

```
Sun Apr 08 1979 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
```

to `YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss`, but in the date data type not the string data type? I'm having difficulty in changing this, as it is converted to string format using moment.

Comment: If you have tried please edit your post to add in the code. This is not a coding community.

Comment: formatting, avoided redundancy

Answer (score 0):

Pass your string to Date, Like this way

In componet:

```
newdate = new Date('Sun Apr 08 1979 00:00:00 GMT+0800');
```

In Html:

```
<p>Formatted Date: <b>{{ newdate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd[T]HH:mm:ss' }}</b> </p>
```

[Demo:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-pipe)

Comment: what im trying to accomplish here is to convert this Sun Apr 08 1979 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)  to YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss retaining its date datatype

Comment: you have wrong date format, it will be 'yyyy-MM-dd[T]HH:mm:ss'

Comment: yes already corrected it. but im not using this data for display its for filtering of data with date data type